# Jenkins Plugins are not installed : Command Line

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ami

I am trying to install jenkins plugins from AWS S3 bucket.

Code for installing jenkins plugins :

```
plugin_manager_url="https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/releases/download/2.12.3/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.3.jar"
jpath="/var/lib/jenkins"

echo "Installing Jenkins Plugin Manager..."
wget -O $${jpath}/jenkins-plugin-manager.jar $${plugin_manager_url}
chown jenkins:jenkins $${jpath}/jenkins-plugin-manager.jar

cd $${jpath}
mkdir pluginsInstalled  
aws s3 cp "s3://bucket/folder-with-plugins.zip" .
unzip folder-with-plugins.zip
echo 'Installing Jenkins Plugins...'
cd plugins/
for plugin in *.jpi; do
    java -jar $${jpath}/jenkins-plugin-manager.jar --war /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --plugin-download-directory $${jpath}/pluginsInstalled --plugins $(echo $plugin | cut -f 1 -d '.')
done
chown -R jenkins:jenkins $${jpath}/pluginsInstalled
systemctl start jenkins //before installing plugins Jenkins is installed, which is up and running
```

IN above code snippet, I unzipped s3 bucket folder, where all plugins are inside "plugins/" folder with .jpi extention so I trimmed that extention while
installing plugins and installed plugins will be in "pluginsInstalled" folder

I have DEV and PROD aws accounts. I will build an AMI using EC2 image builder in DEV account and will share/use that AMI in prod for security reasons.
So, the userdata script for installing jenkins and plugins is part of building AMI. When I check EC2 Image builder's Build Instance, I can see userdata is installed propelry.
But, when I check same AMI which is used in PROD, then I cannot see Jenkins Plugins installed.

Jenkins Version : 2.346.2

And the error log for jenkins is,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No hudson.security.AuthorizationStrategy implementation found for folderBased
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$lookupDescriptor$11(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:211)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(Option.java:321)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lookupDescriptor(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:210)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$configure$3(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:84)
    at io.vavr.Tuple2.apply(Tuple2.java:238)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:83)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:92)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:55)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:350)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:286)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$8(ConfigurationAsCode.java:776)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:712)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:776)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:761)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:637)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:306)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:298)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1158)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:291)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1193)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:983)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
```

When I check jenkins status on PROD where plugins installed AMI is used, somehow jenkins is not able to restart. It gives following error for jenkins status

```
Aug 18 21:08:40 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server...
Aug 18 21:08:45 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: Exception in thread "Attach Listener" Agent failed to start!
Aug 18 21:08:50 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
Aug 18 21:08:50 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$...s,int)
Aug 18 21:08:50 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.g...ava7$1
Aug 18 21:08:50 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal ref...ations
Aug 18 21:08:50 ip-10-220-74-95.ec2.internal jenkins[6656]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: You didn't add the error. Also, how is this related to terraform?

Comment: Additionally, you need to restart the `jenkins` service after installing plugins. It is already running after installation.

Comment: @MarkoE Please check error log & updated tags. thanx !

Comment: @MattSchuchard I tried that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was,
I was installing plugins using,

```
java -jar ./jenkins-plugin-manager.jar --war ./jenkins.war --plugin-download-directory <dir> --plugins <plugins_list>
```

Here, while it was installing plugins with latest jenkins version.
In my case, I updated targeted jenkins version I am using in our project

```
sudo java -jar ./jenkins-plugin-manager.jar --jenkins-version <JENNKINS_VERSION> --plugin-download-directory <dir> --plugins <plugins_list>
```